# Rewrite subdomain do different domain without trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

please I would appreciate some help with htaccess.
The following doesn't work as required

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.acme\.sk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.sk/%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I get `https://example.sk/test/` instead `https://example.sk/test` (tested via http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

How should I rewrite to avoid the last trailing slash?

```
$ curl -ILk http://rady.pracloveka.sk
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 29 Nov 2017 12:21:11 GMT
Location: https://modernypraclovek.sk/rady/
```

Comment: Post your full .htaccess as other rules might be causing this behavior.

Comment: I know, but that's all

Comment: Test it from command line `curl` and post output of `curl -ILk 'http:/test.example.sk/'`